# Entry ID using #id or data-status-id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is good practice to put entry id (via db) into `<tr>`

There are to way doing it.

1) `<tr data-status-id="123"> .. </tr>`

2) `<tr id="status_id_123"> .. </tr>`

For number 2, the code will be a lot shorter I think, for example:

```
$("#status_id" + id).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100)
```

Comment: If you think it pollutes the DOM ID namespace then go with the data attr. Otherwise, personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

I like using data-id attribute. Then I can later give it a class and if I want to select a specific element I can just do this:

```
$("[data-id=whatever]")
```

or

```
$(".some_class[data-id=whatever]")
```

I feel it is better because if you have id values that are the same on other elements for example numbers like 1, 2, 3 it can very easily be duplicate. You don't want duplicate id attributes.